# Angular - How to delay HTTP Requests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an application that loops through an array and makes an API call for each object in the array. The issue is all of the requests are being fired at once. The delay operator is completly ignored.

```
 public StartIt() {

    const len = this.stocks.length;
    console.log(len);

    for (const el of this.stocks) {
      this.iex.getFiveDay(el.Symbol).subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.ops.getVolAvg(res);
        this.datax.push(res);

      });



    }
  } 



 public getFiveDay(symbol) {
    const url: any = this.getApiUrl(symbol, iexEndPointType.fiveday);
    console.log('IEX SERVICE - getFiveDay(): ' + url);
    return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(delay(5000));
  }
```

Comment: So what's the expected behavior? Should the requests be fired sequentially?

Comment: The expected behavior is a delay of 5 seconds between each loop

Comment: `delay(N)` will simply delay the emitted values, not the subscription moment. Did you try `concat()` ?

Comment: why just 5 second delay, if previous request somehow not responded in given time, what should be expected behaviour?

Comment: @Anks, the concern is that the API throttles the request rate.

Comment: Oh! that way, thanks for clarification :)

Comment: I'd recommend using a queuing library which would allow you to do X concurrent requests (which will be faster) and don't have blocking (like with `setTimeout`). I personally like async/queue: https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add fixed delay of 5s for every request, then this might help you

```
const all = [1,2,3,4,5];
all.forEach((each, i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(each); // Call your http request
  }, i * 5000)
});
```